# How do I convert the JSON string to [object][object] format in Angular 6?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular6

How do I convert the below into the [[object][object]] format in Angular 6?

```
resultArray = [{Q_id: "5bbee2fbbb34b98be0464c73", opt_id: 111},{Q_id: "5bbee2fbbb34b98be0464c73", opt_id: 113}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly is in the object. In general I'd try `JSON.stringify(object)`.